# NSMutableArray adds same NSDictionary multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am looping through an array, getting two items and putting them in a dictionary, and then add them to an array, but it keeps adding the last item of the array for the number objects in the array, even though when I log the dictionary inside the loop it has the correct value. Here is my code

```
            for (TFHppleElement *element in nodesArray) {

    [nameAndHrefDict setObject:[element objectForKey:@"href"] forKey:@"href"];
    [nameAndHrefDict setObject:[element text] forKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"PRE: %@", nameAndHrefDict);
    [arrayOfDicts addObject:nameAndHrefDict];
    NSLog(@"IN: %@", arrayOfDicts);


}
```

In the log I see this

```
PRE: {
href = "/dining-choices/res/index.html";
name = "Commons Dining Hall";
}

IN: (
    {
    href = "/dining-choices/res/index.html";
    name = "Commons Dining Hall";
}
PRE: {
href = "/dining-choices/res/sage.html";
name = "Russell Sage Dining Hall";
}

IN: (
    {
    href = "/dining-choices/res/sage.html";
    name = "Russell Sage Dining Hall";
},
    {
    href = "/dining-choices/res/sage.html";
    name = "Russell Sage Dining Hall";
}
)
```

What is happening?

But it add the last value of nodesArray 8 times, instead of each value, why?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You're adding THE SAME DICTIONARY multiple times.  *Of course* you get multiple copies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `alloc` and `init` the array each time, so that there is new memory for it and then it wont add the same array 8 times

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
 for (TFHppleElement *element in nodesArray) {

      [arrayOfDicts addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[element objectForKey:@"href"], @"href", [element text], @"name", nil]];
 }
```

Comment: great that worked? but why wasn't what I was doing before?, I tried alloc and init each time at the being of the loop and that also made it work but Im not sure why?

Comment: You are overwriting the previous objects with the same keys.

Comment: right, but then why does it add that object two or three times? when its overwritten isn't it gone?

Comment: I should not use the word "overwrite".  All the objects you added are still in the array, but because the pointer to the item of the element changes when you loop through TFHppleElement, and after the loop is finished.  All pointers point to your last element.

Comment: The solution is actually to have each item of your arrayOfDicts contains a unique NSDictionary instance.  That is why when you do alloc init, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are added to arrays by reference. The array doesn't create a copy of the dictionary, it just keeps a record of which dictionary has been added. You're adding the same dictionary, `nameAndHrefDict`, to the array every time. So the array considers itself to hold the same object multiple times.

At each iteration you are changing the value of that object but it is still the same object.

So the underlying issue is identify versus value. An array is populated by identity. You're expecting it to populate by value.

To fix: copy the dictionary when you add it to the array, or just create a brand new dictionary from scratch each time.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to instantiate the dictionary in the loop : see the code**

NSMutableArray *saveData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
for (int i=0; i<records.count; i++) {

    RecordTable *record = [records objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *addID = record.addr_id;

    NSMutableDictionary *saveToDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [saveToDic setValue:addID forKey:@"addr_id"];

    [saveData addObject:saveToDic];

    }
```